# Can you compare regression slopes from a mixed model?

Tags: mixed-model

I know that we can do a t-test to compare the slopes of 2 independent regressions line using the coefficients and standard error (example is here: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2009-April/195079.html)

Does this same approach work for mixed models?

Comment: Are these from to separate mixed models or two slopes in one mixed model?

Comment: slopes from 2 separate mixed models.  1 mixed model for 1993-2004 and one for 2005-2010.

Comment: Also, how would you compare the slopes if they are in one mixed model?  I only know how to compare the slopes from 2 separate regression lines.

Comment: So to be totally clear: there is a random intercept but there is *no* random slope in these models?

Answer (score 2):

Testing in one model would be done by simply adding an interaction term.  A significant interaction term would show the slopes are different.

If you're testing across two models you could get the confidence intervals of each slope in each model.  Then, use those to infer whether the slopes are different.  With R and the lme4 package, if your model was `m` then...

```
confint(m)
```

will get you confidence intervals of your slopes (all fixed effects actually). You might want to use a bootstrapped CI in this case. Check help on `confint.merMod`.

Answer (score 1):

In ordinary linear regression the regression parameters will have parallel lines (equal slopes) if there is no interaction between the group and the covariate.  Testing equality of slopes is the same as test for an interaction between the covariate and the group.